# how to select a temp table in database when debugging?

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

I create a temp table #temp1 in code, then insert the table in code. I want to select the table in sqlserver when debugging the code. but It can’t . sql server Prompt no talbe called the name . even in database tempdb. how to select a temp table in database  when debugging?

Comment: try double ##temp1 when creating and accessing. It makes it global

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
insert into ##temp1 select * from TableName
select * from ##temp1
```

**Explanation:**

We need to put **"##"** with the name of Global temporary tables. Below is the syntax for creating a Global Temporary Table:

```
CREATE TABLE ##NewGlobalTempTable(
UserID int,
UserName varchar(50), 
UserAddress varchar(150))
```

The above script will create a temporary table in tempdb database. We can insert or delete records in the temporary table similar to a general table like:

```
insert into ##NewGlobalTempTable values ( 1, 'Abhijit','India');
```

Now select records from that table:

```
select * from ##NewGlobalTempTable
```

Global temporary tables are visible to all SQL Server connections. When you create one of these, all the users can see it.